# pass selected photos from <ImageBrowswer> to Button using expo-image-picker-multiple react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a React Native IOS App.I have a page where I want to display the images in the phone camera and select multiple photos from them and then add the photos to Google Platform bucket.Below is the code to store the selected photos to an array.

ImageBrowserScreen.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator ,Button} from 'react- 
native';
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';
import {ImageBrowser} from 'expo-image-picker-multiple';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class ImageBrowserScreen extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
this.getPermissionAsync();
}


getPermissionAsync = async () => {
if (Constants.platform.ios) {
const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
if (status !== 'granted') {
alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
}
}
};

imagesCallback = (callback) => {
var image = [];
callback.then((photos) => {
//Assigning all photos selected to an array
image = photos;
console.log('List of photos'+photos);
}).catch((e) => console.log(e))
};


renderSelectedComponent = (number) => (
<View style={styles.countBadge}>
<Text style={styles.countBadgeText}>{number}</Text>
</View>
);

render() {
const emptyStayComponent = <Text style={styles.emptyStay}>Empty =(</Text>;

return (
<View style={[styles.flex, styles.container]}>
<ImageBrowser
  max={4}
  renderSelectedComponent={this.renderSelectedComponent}
  emptyStayComponent={emptyStayComponent}
  
/>
<Button  title="Add Photos" onPress={this.imagesCallback}/>
</View>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
flex: {
flex: 1
},
container: {
position: 'relative'
},
emptyStay:{
textAlign: 'center',
},
countBadge: {
paddingHorizontal: 8.6,
paddingVertical: 5,
borderRadius: 50,
position: 'absolute',
right: 3,
bottom: 3,
justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#0580FF'
},
countBadgeText: {
fontWeight: 'bold',
alignSelf: 'center',
padding: 'auto',
color: '#ffffff'
}
});
```

After running the above code I am getting the following error:

```
 TypeError:callback.then is not a function.(In 'callback.then((photos) => {
    //Assigning all photos selected to an array
    image = photos;
    console.log('List of photos'+photos);
    })','calback.then' is undefined)
```

I want the Images array to send to node API which stores the images to the Google Cloud Platform bucket.

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call `callback.then()`, your `imagesCallback` function must receive an argument callback which is a `Promise`.

That isn’t happening.  You are using `imagesCallback` as the `onPress` prop on your `Button`.  The argument which is passed to an `onPress` handler is the press event.  The event is not a `Promise` and has no `.then()` property, so it doesn’t match the expected argument of your `imagesCallback` function.

**Edit:** Your `imagesCallback` needs to access the `ImagePicker` library in order to know what photos are selected.  [This example](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#usage) in the docs shows how it's done.  `pickImage` takes no arguments and calls a method on the global `ImagePicker`.

```
  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };
```

The `result` for an image is an object with properties `cancelled`, `height`, `width` and `uri`.

Your `imagesCallback` might possibly work if you provide it with a `callback`.  At least you'll get a different error!

```
import {launchImageLibraryAsync} from 'expo-image-picker-multiple';
```

```
<Button
   title="Add Photos" 
   onPress={() => this.imagesCallback(launchImageLibraryAsync)}
/>
```

Comment: ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker' will allow us to select only one photo at once, multiple select is not allowed (Note:allowsMultipleSelection (boolean) -- (Web only) Whether or not to allow selecting multiple media files at once).I want to select multiple photos and store them in an array. So I am trying to use ImageBrowser from 'expo-image-picker-multiple'.

Comment: My bad, I didn’t notice that you were importing from a custom package and not ‘expo-image-picker’.  I’ll check the package docs.  It looks you want to give a callback to the ImagePicker component rather than to a Button.

Comment: Ok so in their demo https://snack.expo.io/@monstrodev/expo-image-picker-multiple-full-example they have a `Button` in `./screens/MainScreen` and the button's `onPress` triggers navigating to the screen in `./screens/ImageBrowserScreen`.  This screen is where you got your `callback.then()` from.  The `imagesCallback` **is passed to the `ImageBrowser` component, not the `Button` component** because your button doesn't know anything about the images.  I can tweak this code to work on one page without the navigation.  But yeah the issue is passing your callback to the wrong component.

Comment: It took me a while but I finally figured it out: https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/expo-image-picker-multiple-full-example

Comment: Thank you so much @Linda Paiste for your time and inputs.Its selecting the multiple photos.Will work on the code to continue the process of storing the photos to google cloud bucket.